# Realizar busqueda por fecha en una bd en asp.net

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy realizando una web en ASP.NET MVC 5 que muestre una lista de personas, actualmente solo muestra las que estan en ese dia, pero como la bd almacena todos los dias quiero crear una vista que sea estilo historial que pongan el dia que quieren mostrar y que este haga esa consulta en la base de datos pero por mas que busco no logro encontrar como hacer para que de la vista manden una fecha y este actualice la vista con los resultados de ese dia.

tengo dos modelos

```
public class Articulo
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set;  }
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Comentario { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    }


  public List<Articulo> RecuperarHistorial(DateTime fecha)
        {
            Conectar();
            List<Articulo> articulos = new List<Articulo>();
            fechacomp = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand("select * From registro where fecha = '" + fechacomp + "';", con);
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlDataReader registros = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (registros.Read())
            {
                Articulo art = new Articulo
                {

                    Nombre = registros["nombre"].ToString(),
                    Id = int.Parse(registros["id"].ToString()),
                    Comentario = registros["comentario"].ToString(),
                    Fecha = DateTime.Parse(registros["fecha"].ToString()),
                };
                articulos.Add(art);
            }
            con.Close();
            return articulos;
        }
```

y quiero crear una vista que pueda mandarle la fecha a esa consulta pero no se como hacerlo lo intente pero como es una lista no funciono y estoy totalmente perdido

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que observo te falta cerrar la comilla simple:

```
        NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand("select * From registro where fecha = '" + fechacomp + ";", con);
```

Debería quedar así:

```
        NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand("select * From registro where fecha = '" + fechacomp + "';", con);
```

Comment: No tengo problema con el query, tengo problema con que no se como enviar la informacion de la fecha que quiero buscar, ese es el problema en realidad